# Best way to send e-mail from dedicated server

Tags: .net, asp.net, architecture

I have web application (asp.net) located on web server. I need to send email asynchronously from other server (task server) because web server is high loaded. I plan to store mail in database. Are there other way or out of the box solution?

Comment: You are optimizing the wrong stuff. I don't think that sending an email takes more CPU than storing the email in a database. At least not so much more that it outweights the extra hassle. Find other bottle necks instead. (Mass email is another thing though)

Comment: Why email? Why not some type of messaging system: MSMQ, Jabber, RabbitMR, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas...

**Option 1: Central Email Database**

Web App on web server (?) writes email to database; "Task Server" application on a differnet box reads database for email info, etc.  Presumably the database is on it's own box or with the task server.

**Option 2: WCF Queue**

WCF allows different bindings, a queue based binding is one of them.  for this to work you'll need to define service contracts that don't return values to the caller (in your case: the web app).

I'm assuming here that the web app would just call the WCF directly, which basically replaces the need for the database - assuming that was all it was there for.

**Option 3: Config**

From memory, you could just config your app to send email via an SMTP server located elsewhere - although I guess this would be synchronous.